# Mutable State and the Observer Pattern

Tags: f#, observer-pattern, mutable

I'm currently redeveloping an application in F# and, while the experience has been excellent, I find myself a little bewildered when it comes to controlling mutability.

Previously, the document model used by my C# program was highly mutable and implemented ObservableCollections and INotifyPropertyChanged that shared state between views wouldn't bug out. Clearly, this isn't an ideal, especially if I want a fully immutable approach to my designs.

With that in mind I created a non-observable, immutable, document model for my underlying application kernel but, because I want a UI subscriber to see changes I immediately found myself implementing event-driven patterns:

```
// Raw data.
type KernelData = { DocumentContent : List<string> }

// Commands that act on the data.
type KernelCommands = { AddString : string -> () }

// A command implementation. Performs a state change, echos the new state through the event.
let addStringCommand (kernelState : KernelData) (kernelChanged : Event<KernelData>) (newString : string) =
    kernelState with { DocumentContent=oldList |> List.add newString }
    |> kernelChanged.Trigger

// Time to wire this up.
do
    // Create some starting state.
    let kernelData = { DocumentContent=List.Empty }

    // Create a shared event that commands may use to inform observers (UI).
    let kernelChangedEvent = new Event<KernelData>()

    // Create the command, it uses the event to inform observers.
    let kernelCommands = { AddString=addString kernelData kernelChangedEvent }

    // Create a UI element that uses the commands to initialize data transformations. UI elements subscribed to the data use the event to listen.
    let myUI = new UiObject(kernelData, kernelChangedEvent.Publish, kernelCommands)
    myUI.Show()
```

So this has been my solution to passing new state to the relevant listeners. However, what would be more ideal is a "box" I can "hook" into with transform functions. When the box mutates, functions are called to deal with the new state and produce corresponding changed state in a UI component.

```
do
    // Lambda called whenever the box changes.
    idealBox >>= (fun newModel -> new UIComponent(newModel))
```

So I guess I'm asking if there is an observable pattern for dealing with these situations. Mutable state is normally handled using monads but I've only seen examples which involve performing the operation (e.g. piping console IO monads, loading files, etc.) and not actually dealing with persistently mutating state.

Comment: How do you see that the model you already have differs from your idealbox model? In my opinion having an IEvent<State> or IObservable<State> is exactly what you describe: Hook into the box with transforming functions that is called when the box mutates.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for the feedback. Would it be fair to say that my current implementation is acceptable then? At the moment I am passing around (and transforming) an IEvent<KernelData>. It seems to 'work'. The only issue being that any command (transformer) functions will need access to the Event<KernelData> for triggering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My general solution for these scenarios is to build all business logic in a purely functional setting and then provide a thin service layer with the necessary functionality for synchronizing and propagating changes. Here's an example of a pure interface for your `KernelData` type:

```
type KernelData = { DocumentContent : List<string> }
let emptyKernelData = {DocumentContent = []}
let addDocument c kData = {kData with DocumentContent = c :: kData.DocumentContent}
```

I would then define a service layer interface wrapping the functionality for modifying and subscribing to changes:

```
type UpdateResult = 
    | Ok
    | Error of string

/// Service interface
type KernelService =
{
    /// Gets the current kernel state.
    Current : unit -> KernelData

    /// Subscribes to state changes.
    Subscribe : (KernelData -> unit) -> IDisposable

    /// Modifies the current kernel state.
    Modify : (KernelData -> KernelData) -> Async<UpdateResult>
}
```

The `Async` responses enable non-blocking updates. The `UpdateResult` type is used to signal whether update operations succeeded or not. In order to build a sound `KernelService` object it's important to realize that modification requests need to by synchronized to avoid data loss from parallel updates. For this purpose `MailboxProcessor`s come in handy. Here's a `buildKernelService` function that constructs a service interface given an initial `KernelData` object.

```
// Builds a service given an initial kernel data value.
let builKernelService (def: KernelData) =

    // Keeps track of the current kernel data state.
    let current = ref def

    // Keeps track of update events.
    let changes = new Event<KernelData>()

    // Serves incoming requests for getting the current state.
    let currentProc :  MailboxProcessor<AsyncReplyChannel<KernelData>> =
        MailboxProcessor.Start <| fun inbox ->
            let rec loop () =
                async {
                    let! chn = inbox.Receive ()
                    chn.Reply current.Value
                    return! loop ()
                }
            loop ()

    // Serves incoming 'modify requests'.
    let modifyProc : MailboxProcessor<(KernelData -> KernelData) * AsyncReplyChannel<UpdateResult>> =
        MailboxProcessor.Start <| fun inbox ->
            let rec loop () =
                async {
                    let! f, chn = inbox.Receive ()
                    let v = current.Value
                    try
                        current := f v
                        changes.Trigger current.Value
                        chn.Reply UpdateResult.Ok
                    with
                    | e ->
                        chn.Reply (UpdateResult.Error e.Message)
                    return! loop ()
                }
            loop ()
    {
        Current = fun () -> currentProc.PostAndReply id
        Subscribe = changes.Publish.Subscribe
        Modify = fun f -> modifyProc.PostAndAsyncReply (fun chn -> f, chn)
    }
```

Note that there is nothing in the implementation above that is unique to `KernelData` so the service interface along with the *build* function can be generalized to arbitrary types of internal states.

Finally, some examples of programming with `KernelService` objects:

```
// Build service object.
let service = builKernelService emptyKernelData

// Print current value.
let curr = printfn "Current state: %A" service.Current

// Subscribe 
let dispose = service.Subscribe (printfn "New State: %A")


// Non blocking update adding a document
service.Modify <| addDocument "New Document 1"

// Non blocking update removing all existing documents.
service.Modify (fun _ -> emptyKernelData)

// Blocking update operation adding a document.
async {
    let! res = service.Modify (addDocument "New Document 2")
    printfn "Update Result: %A" res
    return ()
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously

// Blocking update operation eventually failing.
async {
    let! res = 
        service.Modify (fun kernelState ->
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 10000
            failwith "Something terrible happened"
        )
    printfn "Update Result: %A" res
    return ()
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Besides the more technical details, I believe the most important difference from your original solution is that special *command* functions are not needed. Using the service layer, any pure function operating on `KernelData` (e.g addDocument) can be lifted into a stateful computation using the `Modify` function.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. I recently read "Real world functional programming" that talked through the mailbox global state but found it hard to conceptualize when I have nested document objects etc so this is really helpful to see it with more pertinent content!

Comment: Great reply. I wonder though if there's any specific reason why you access the current state through an Actor instead of just getting it directly from the reference?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that update operations are synchronized by the actor so that multiple update operations from concurrent clients are processed in a sequence. That is one update operation must complete before the next one is applied. This is important in order to prevent data loss.