# Immutable State - Propagating Changes to the GUI Efficiently

Tags: wpf, user-interface, f#, immutability, observer-pattern

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814700/mutable-state-and-the-observer-pattern) I asked how to idiomatically implement an observer pattern for an F# application. My application now uses a [MailboxProcessor](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/MailboxProcessor) as reccomended and I've created some helper functions to create sub-MailboxProcessor's etc. However, I'm at a mental block when it comes to specific case scenarios w.r.t. GUI binding.

Lets say I have a model as such:

```
type Document = {
    Contents : seq<DocumentObject>
}
```

And the GUI (WPF, XAML) requires binding like so:

```
interface IMainWindowViewModel
{
    IEnumerable<Control> ContentViews { get; }
}
```

Each `ViewModel` for each `Control` will require a `DocumentObject` (its underlying model) and a way of knowing if it has changed. I supply this as a sub-`MailboxProcessor<DocumentObject>` so that changes may be propagated correctly, I'm moderately confident this pattern works. Essentially, it maps the service outputs and wraps modification requests (outer interface example below):

```
let subSvc = generateSubSvc svc (fun doc -> doc.Contents[0]) (fun f -> fun oldDoc -> { oldDoc with Contents[0] = f Contents[0] })
let viewModel = new SomeDocObjViewModel(docObjSvc)
new DocObjView(viewModel)
```

Now, imagine a modification command now deletes a `DocumentObject` from `MyDocument`. The top-level `MailboxProcessor` now echoes the change to `IMainWindowViewModel` using it's `IEvent<MyDocument>`. And here's where my problems begin.

My `IMainWindowViewModel` doesn't really *know*  which `DocumentObject` has been deleted. Only that there's a new `Document` and it has to deal with it. There may be ways of it figuring out but it never really *knows* directly. This can force me down the path of having to either re-create all the `Control`'s for all `DocumentObject`'s to be safe (inefficient). There are additional problems (such as dangling `subSvc`'s) which I also haven't mentioned here for brevity.

Normally, these kind of dynamic changes would be dealt with something like an `ObservableCollection<DocumentObject>` which is then mapped into an `ObservableCollection<Control>`. This comes with all the caveats of shared mutable state and is a little 'hackish'; however, it does do the job.

Ideally, I'd like a 'pure' model, free from the trappings of `PropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollections`, what kind of patterns in F# would satisfy this need? Where is it appropriate to draw the line between *idiomatic* and *realistic*?

Comment: F# MVC framework for WPF https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/fsharp-wpf-mvc-series

Comment: Hey, thanks for this series. I've been reading it as I get a spare break here and there. It's been very insightful. However, one criticism I might have is that it appears to be directly adapting a standard (Castle MVC) approach into F# from C#, give or take a discriminated union here and there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Reactive Extensions](http://rx.codeplex.com/) (and [Reactive UI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) further down the road) for the purpose of modelling mutable state (read: your model properties over time) in a functional way?

I don't see anything wrong technically to use an `ObservableCollection` in your model. After all, you *need* to track collection changes. You could do it on your own, but it looks like you can save yourself a lot of trouble reinventing the observable collection, unless you have a very specific reason to avoid the `ObservableCollection` class.

Also, using `MailboxProcessor` seems a bit overkill, since you could just use a `Subject` (from Rx) to publish and expose it as an `IObservable` to subscribe to 'messages':

```
type TheModel() =
    let charactersCountSubject = new Subject()
    let downloadDocument (* ... *) = async {
        let! text = // ...
        charactersCountSubject.OnNext(text.Length)
    }        

    member val CharactersCount = charactersCountSubject.AsObservable() with get

type TheViewModel(model : TheModel) =
    // ...
    member val IsTooManyCharacters = model.CharactersCount.Select((>) 42)
```

Of course since we're talking about WPF, the view-model should implement `INPC`. There are different approaches, but whichever one you take, the `ReactiveUI` has a lot of convenient tools.

For example the `CreateDerivedCollection` extension method that solves one of the problems you've mentioned:

```
documents.CreateDerivedCollection(fun x -> (* ... map Document to Control ... *))
```

This will take your `documents` observable collection, and make another observable collection out of it (actually a `ReactiveCollection`) that will have documents mapped to controls.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for this answer. It seems, as I've been reading around, that your approach is the most realistic. Ideally, I'd *love* to have a clean model without any GUI considerations but it does appear that all the tooling (`Rx` etc.) is geared toward it. I'm somewhat fighting an uphill battle trying to have my cake and eat it here. Thank you for the contribution.